# Get the database content posted on a selected option into a form with single fields

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, forms

I have a form with a select. The options are coming from a database and displayed into the select.

The columns on the database are:

```
id, date, title, body.
```

On the select I display only date and title. In the same page I have a form with:

```
 date -> input text
 title -> input text
 body -> text area
```

I want that when an option from the select is clicked by the user the fields below will be update with the content kept from the selected option which contain the database data.

Now I have no idea how to get the data on the fields below.
My idea was to get the index of the option of the drop down. Is this possible?

EDIT COMPLETE CODE:

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="normal">
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="174"><strong>geste n</strong></td>

        <td width="505" valign="middle" height="24">

            <input type="radio" name="n" id="new" value="nuova" onchange="shown(this.id);" <?php if($_POST['n'] == "nuova"){echo "CHECKED";} ?> />Nuova n
            <input type="radio" name="n" id="mod" value="modifica" onchange="shown(this.id);" <?php if($_POST['n'] == "modifica"){echo "CHECKED";} ?> />Modifica n
                <select id="sceltannascosta" style="display:none">
                    <?php
                        include("/login/flock/sql.php");
                        $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db) or die("Impossibile connettersi"); 
                        $a = "SELECT * FROM n ORDER BY id DESC";
                        $b = mysqli_query($conn, $a);                       
                            print '<option></option>';                      
                        while ($c = $b->fetch_object()) {
                            print '<option>'.$c->id.$c->data.$c->title.$c->body.'</option>';
                        }
                        $b->close();
                        $conn->close;      
                    ?>    
                </select>

                <select id="sceltan" style="display:none" onChange="showEntry(this,this.value);setndamod(this);">
                    <?php
                        include("/login/flock/sql.php");
                        $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db) or die("Impossibile connettersi"); 
                        $a = "SELECT * FROM n ORDER BY id DESC";
                        $b = mysqli_query($conn, $a);                       
                            print '<option></option>';                      
                        while ($c = $b->fetch_object()) {
                            print '<option>'.$c->data.' - '.$c->title.'</option>';
                        }
                        $b->close();
                        $conn->close;      
                    ?>  
                </select>                
            <input type="submit" id="botenascostogeste" class="button">       
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="normal" id="c" style="display:none">
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <tr>
      <td colspan="3" border="0">
        <strong class="confirm">c nuova n</strong>
      </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="107" align="right">
        <strong>Data</strong>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <form name="nuovan" method="post" action="cht.php?c=yes">
            <input name="datan" type="text" maxlength="10" size="8" value="<?php echo date(d.".".m.".".Y) ?>"> gg.mm.aaaa
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <strong>Titolo</strong>
      <td width="360">
                <input name="titolon" type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" value="<? echo htmlspecialchars("titolo n - lunghezza massima 50 caratteri") ?>" onKeyPress="return taLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return taCount(this,'myCounter')">
      </td>
      <td width="522">
          <b><span id=myCounter>6</span></b> caratteri rimanenti per il titolo</font>
      </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
                <textarea name="teston"><?php if(isset($_POST['teston'])){echo $_POST['teston'];}else{echo 'Testo n con stile personalizzato';} ?></textarea>
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace('teston');
                </script>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="c" class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('botenascostogeste').click();">
    </form>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
    <?php
        $c = $_GET['c'];                
        $titolon = $_POST['titolon'];
        $teston = $_POST['teston'];
        $datascritta = $_POST['datan'];

        if($c == 'yes'){                        
            if($_POST['titolon'] == NULL || $_POST['teston'] == NULL || $_POST['datan'] == NULL){
                echo '<img src="'.$imagen.'" style=width:"' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;">';
            } else {

                function verificadata($datascritta) { 
                    list($dd,$mm,$yyyy)=explode(".",$datascritta); 
                    if (is_numeric($dd) && is_numeric($mm) && is_numeric($yyyy)) 
                    { 
                        return checkdate($mm,$dd,$yyyy); 
                    } 
                    return false;            
                }

                if(verificadata($datascritta)){
                    $connessione = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $pw) or     //connect to the database 
                        die('<img src="'.$imagen.'" style=width:"' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;">');                                                    
                    mysql_select_db ($db); //select the database                
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO n(data, title, body) VALUES ('$datascritta', '$titolon', '$teston')");
                    mysql_close($connessione);
                    echo ('<img src="'.$imagey.'" style=width:"' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;"> Ok'); // It worked.
                } else { die('<img src="'.$imagen.'" style=width:"' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;">');                                                   
                }
            }
        }
    ?>    
    </td>
</table>
</div>

<div class="normal" id="modifica" style="display:none">
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <tr>
      <td colspan="3" border="0">
        <strong class="confirm">Modifica n</strong>
      </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="107" align="right">
        <strong>Data</strong>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <form name="modifican" method="post" action="cht.php?modifica=yes">
            <input name="idmodifican" type="text" style="display:none" value="INSERIRE ID DI MODIFICA DEL DATABASE QUI">
            <input name="datanmodificata" type="text" maxlength="10" size="8" value="POST DATE FROM THE n TO MODIFY SELECTED"> gg.mm.aaaa
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <strong>Titolo</strong>
      </td>
      <td width="360">
                <input name="modificatitolo" type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" value="POST TITLE FROM THE n TO MODIFY SELECTED" onKeyPress="return taLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return taCount(this,'myCounter')">
      </td>
      <td width="522">
          <b><span id=myCounter>50</span></b> caratteri rimanenti per il titolo</font>
      </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
                <textarea name="modificatesto">POST BODY FROM THE n TO MODIFY SELECTED</textarea>
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace('modificatesto');
                </script>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="modifica" class="button">
    </form>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
    PHP I HAVE TO DO TO UPDATE THE n ON THE DATABASE (I'm able to do this part).
    </td>
</table>
</div>  

</body>
```

Comment: Neat idea! [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Do you have a question about how this is accomplished? Because right it sounds more like you're asking someone to build this system for you, which is NOT what this site is about.

Comment: Use jQuery/Js (ajax) to populate the `select` options when the parent `select` index changes.

Comment: I added some text I tried without success...

Comment: can you provide more code detail so that i can try :)

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to make ajax call.
 then use jquery to get the field set up depending upon the value selected in the select field you can set the value of the other fields  try this modify it according to your need

```
<body>
    <form>
        <select id="sel_opt">
        <?php 
          $i = 1;
          foreach($valueformdb as $value)
          {
              echo "<option class=\"option\" id=\"opt_$i\">";
              echo $value;
              echo '</option>';
              $i++;
          }

        ?>    
        </select>
       <input type="text" id="txt_date" value="" />
       <input type="text" id="txt_title" value="" />
       <textarea id="ta_body"></textarea>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.sel_opt').on('change', function(){
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          url:" ",// path of file to handle ajax request
          data:'option='+id, // this will be posted on the page which handle the ajax and give back the data from db
          success:function(data){
              $('#txt_date').val(data[date]);// ajax respond the array containg the value its advised to use json
              $('#txt_title').val(data[title]);
             }
          });
       });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

this is not the exact code you need to modify a bit, cause i don't know the exact thing you are trying to achieve